# extension like django-evolution

Tags: django, django-evolution

I am in search for a extension that is similar to django_-volution.
The requirement is to alter the database, whitout deleting the wohle data.

I don't know, but for me, this is something so ordinary - doesn't django have a built-in function like that?

django_evolution is still in working progress and has some bugs, so i want something that is stable and maybe has more options. Especially to write own mutations seems a little bit complex for me.

Does anybody know something similar?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).  It's currently the de-facto schema and data migration plugin for Django.  I believe there have been talks about adding it to the core of Django.  It has a bit of a learning curve but you seriously want to take the time and learn it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd like something to perform 'migrations' a la rails, correct? The best known and most stable project is South, as far as I know. It offers "intelligent schema and data migrations for  Django projects".

http://south.aeracode.org/

Personally, I just alter my model, and make the changes through the database command line client.